# "Busy" icon not spinning in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows, 64-bit, cursor

I just got a new Sony VAIO with Windows 7 pre-installed and noticed that the *busy icon* (that is, the little blue wheel that stays next to the mouse pointer when Windows is processing something) doesn't spin, ever. Does anyone know what could cause this, or how to fix it?

I don't know if my computer specs would make a difference in this case, but here they are:

- VAIO VGN-NW240F
- 4GB RAM
- 320GB HD
- Intel Core 2 Duo
- Windows 7 Home Premium 64-bit

Comment: Je parle seulement un petit peu! En realité, je suis brésilienne. Nous utilisons des accents ici aussi :)

Comment: Il y en a même qui parlent français et n'ont pas d'accents dans le nom! :-)

Comment: Je ne parle pas français, so please keep it English ;-)

Comment: Comment dit-on "lol" en français?

Comment: Please communicate in English for people like me. That's all.

Answer (score 1):

i have this problem and i have found it is to do with the touchpad driver in Sony VIAO and Dell Insperon laptops, i suggest you find an alternate touchpad driver that does not cause this problem  :)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this will work, but do you have Aero/high performance settings enabled? Right-click on Computer and then click Properties and then click to run your Windows Experience Index. This will run your Windows Experience Index and will enable Aero if appropriate (which it sounds like it would be.)

Also, try right-clicking on the desktop, click Personalize, and make sure you have an Aero theme enabled (as opposed to a Basic theme).

Answer (score 0):

Try the **[Windows 7 Aero Busy Cursor Fix](http://www.pretentiousname.com/win7_fixed_aero_busy/index.html)**.

Comment: If the original icon does not spin, I doubt the fixed version (without the missing frame) will work...

Comment: Yes, Snark is right. My problem is that the icon doesn't spin at all (although when I look at it in Control Panel->Mouse->Pointers it looks just fine). And by the way, I don't think I would ever have noticed the missing frame by myself! But now I will definitely fix it... :)